# Formatting a date returned from an Observable array

Tags: json, angular, observablecollection

I am trying to format a date value returned from a rest service as an observable. The createdOn and modifiedOn dates are being rendered in my HTML as /Date(1298937600000)/, I would like them formatted as dd/MM/yyyy. I have seen a few similar posts but none seem to point me in the right direction or are beyond my current understanding of Angular 2.

I am making a call to my API as such:

```
getUnLocationsList(): Observable<UnLocations[]> {

    var url = "http://localhost:5000/api/unlocations"
    return this._http.get(url)
        .map((response: Response) => <UnLocations[]>response.json().unLocations)
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

From my Angular 2 Component I am then calling the getUnLocationsList() function, like this:

```
export class StandingDataComponent implements OnInit {

 pageTitle: string = 'UnLocation Codes';
 unLocationsList: UnLocations[];

 constructor(private _staticDataService: StaticDataService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
 this.getUnLocationsList();
 }
 getUnLocationsList() {
  this._staticDataService.getUnLocationsList().subscribe(unLocationsList => this.unLocationsList = unLocationsList),
  err => console.error(err),
  () => console.log("finished loading unlocations");
```

}

finally I am using then using a simple *ngFor to display the data

```
<tbody *ngFor="let unLocation of unLocationsList | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 30, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index">
    <td style="width:100px"> {{unLocation.code}} </td>
    <td style="width:200px"> {{unLocation.name}} </td>        
    <td style="width:200px">{{unLocation.isActive}}</td>
    <td style="width:200px">{{unLocation.createdOn }}</td>
     <td style="width:200px">{{unLocation.modifiedOn }}</td>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the [DatePipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html) to transform the output of your binding. This will leave your data unchanged, which might be desirable. It's in the CommonModule so you shouldn't have to import anything.

Something like this:

```
<td style="width:200px">{{unLocation.createdOn | date:'dd/MM/y' }}</td>
```

Otherwise you can turn it into a Date object somewhere (loop through them all) and use this:

```
new Date(1298937600000);
// Tue Mar 01 2011 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working. Pipes did not seem to work, however, iterating over each item in the list (as suggested) did the trick. Here's my code

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
    var data = res.json().unLocations || [];
    data.forEach((d) => {
        d.createdOn = new Date(parseInt(d.createdOn.substr(6)));

        if (d.modifiedOn != null)
            d.modifiedOn = new Date(parseInt(d.modifiedOn.substr(6)));
    });
    return data;
}
```